# Interactive tool for editing TIN data

Tags: dem, vector, editing, software-recommendations, rivers

I created TIN to generate DTM using Mass points from Lidar data and river data that I made from stereoplotting. TIN results show there are several locations where the river elevation floats. So I have to improve the elevation data of the floating river so that it is at the correct elevation.

Is there an interactive tool when I edit the elevation of the wrong river then the TIN data changes automatically without me having to re-create the TIN data?

I have tried the TIN editor in ArcGIS but the tools only edit the TIN data.